# How to pass value of hidden input to data() property of Vue instance

Tags: html, vue.js

**.html:**

```
<div id="app">    
 <input type="hidden" name="data" value="Hello" id="data">
</div>
```

**script:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      someData: "",
    };
  },
});
```

I want to pass value(Hello) to someData
I've tried v-model but it don't work with hidden inputs

Comment: where is the `v-model`

Comment: i removed it from code because it didn't help. Can you give me proper code example to bind the data to hidden input?

Comment: it should work, also did you check console for errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're generating that HTML server-side and want to get the value from HTML into Vue, you can simply add a `ref` to the `<input>` and in the `mounted` hook, read the value

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    someData: ""
  }),
  mounted () {
    // read the "value" from the input element
    this.someData = this.$refs.data.value
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!--                 note the new "ref" attribute -->
  <input type="hidden" ref="data" name="data" value="Hello" id="data">

  <!-- just an example to show the data has been assigned -->
  <pre>someData = {{ someData }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to add `ref` or any other changes to the HTML, you can of course query the DOM directly

```js
mounted () {
  this.someData = document.getElementById("data").value
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it is possible without ref? i mean some kind of "v-"  vue things. And sorry i can give thumbs up because i'm less than 15 reputation

Comment: @Farid I've added an example without `ref`